What is the best approach to switching heavy loads with parallel MOSFETs?
I am going to build a spot welder with 20 MOSFETs in parallel (datasheet), each one capable of delivering 550A (1.2 kA peak approx.) powered by 35 mm2 cables connected to a 60 Ah 12 V car battery. In my past tests the whole circuit worked fine (16 mm2 cables and 8 MOSFETs in parallel.) The rated current was 1.7 kA for a few milliseconds. I decided to increase the power increasing the cable gauge since the 80 % of the energy was lost in the cables itself.
Before I started, I came across a problem: the MOSFET sync. There are two ways to address the issue (because, actually, all the components are not identical each other):

Putting a gate resistor and a ferrite bead for each MOSFET case n. 1
Putting a gate resistor and a class B amplifier for each MOSFET case n. 2 (Andy aka show me the PNP BJT should have the emitter at the same pin of NPN, sorry for the mistake);


Obviously, both the cases have symmetrical layout and short wires as much as possible, TVS, fast recovery diode and Drain Source ceramic capacitor are added for safe inductive load turn off. Copper bars and bolts are used, ferrite beads for fast Spike, decoupled Power supply of the MOSFET driver.
The first case I used before; because of the high current, as soon as the MOSFETs close (over slightly inductive load) the not perfect synchronization burns some of them even if they have positive temperature coefficient.
Even with the first option (with different gate capacitance) the closing time can differ, unfortunately the problem persists, a little unbalance causes one or more MOSFETs to overload.
regardless the reason of burn out, Do you think the second case can be more effective the first case? I could reduce the switching time, furthermore the gate capacitance would no longer affects the turn off. On the other hand, the different hfe is a disadvantage, but overall, the class B amplifier has 100 MHz of bandwidth, so it is negligible, thereby the only difference in commutation would be referable to the physical construction of each MOSFET.
I've tried to simulate the spot welder with 2 m of cable length as load:

Case 1 different MOSFETs and gate path traces;
Case 2 different MOSFETs, gate path traces and BJT's class B amplifier.
It seems give me reason...I wait a confirm from you or maybe I do not take into account something else which could affect the results.



Fewer words, more schematics.

The schematic Is Just a resistor to a gate of the mos (case1), while the other has a resistor + a class B to a gate (case2), I believe It's trivivial.

Do you use a capacitor just nearest MOSFETs and "load"? How do you distribute the currents equally in the various MOSFETs?

Hi Antonio, I've added a picture, the only capacitance is due to the gate, for this kind of MOSFETs it's really high, thus the switching time may be critical, 10 us becomes too much. The current distribution is assured by the resistor of 47 Ohm in the picture, it attenuates the oscillations too (ferrite beads are in series further the help the stability during the transition).

I was thinking of a capacitor that is "discharged" by the MOSFETs ... into the "load".

What's a "class B"? Do you mean a BJT complementary emitter follower?

Consider the SOA graph of your mosfets. You’re highly unlikely to achieve 550A per device, 200A with heatsinking is more likely. The other issue is pcb layout - managing 100’s of A on a pcb is very tricky as every track is a resistor. Maintaining correct drive parameters with voltage drops across tracks is hard. At your expected current levels I’d be looking at bus bars. I’d be looking at bigger mosfets as well - much bigger. Ones with bolts for terminals.

Your push-pull stage is drawn incorrectly. However, now I know what you mean by a class B. However, without a full disclosure of what you currently have schematically, you are likely not to get many answers of a decent quality level.

@Andyaka you're right, the PNP Is in the wrong position I drawn it in hurry. Class B amplifier I meant, in any case the other part of the circuit doesn't matter because the only problem consists in finding the best config. for syncronization. As soon as I've time I'll try to simulate both of them on ltspice, then I'll post the results ;-)

Synchronization relies on the drivers and what feeds them. How the drains and sources are connected is also vital. Also, you mention sync so the drivers are important to understand. What was that sync problem you mentioned.

@Andyaka here Is the schematic (no diode 1n4148 are mounted at the Moment), copper bars symmetrical layout Is used for connections to the Gates.
https://oshwlab.com/roby_tas/prova
